# PHP PDO execute statement within a function?

Tags: php, pdo, insert

I have a function that creates a cookie and updates a database with the cookies data accordingly but I can't seem to get the db to update from within the function. `is currently unable to handle this request.`

You can take for granted that the correct data is being fed into the function including $db. I can get the page to load once I comment out the two `$stmt` lines that prepare and execute the insert into the $db.

$db lives in a file call `db.php` which I require before calling the function. I've tested `$db` on other in page queries and it seems to work no problem.

```
function updatecookieDB($db, $email)
{
    $Selector = md5($email);
    $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(20));
    $salt = bin2hex(random_bytes(20));
    $cookiedata = $Selector.$token;
    $Hash = md5($token.$salt);
    setcookie('RememberMe',$cookiedata,time()+(3600*24*15),"/")
    $query = " INSERT INTO RememberMe(email,Selector,Hash,Salt) VALUES (:email,:Selector,:Hash,:Salt) ";
    $query_params = array ( ':email' => $email ,':Selector' => $Selector , ':Hash' => $Hash, ':Salt' => $salt );

    try
    {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute($query_params);
    {
    catch(PDOException $ex) { die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); }


}
```

Could it be because I'm not returning anything?

Comment: So where does $email, $selector, $hash and $salt fall into this function?

Comment: Where's the form side of the code?

Comment: and how you're calling that function

Comment: *"Could it be because I'm not returning anything?"* - If you're not calling that custom function, yeah... it won't do anything.

Comment: function updatecookieDB($db,$Selector,$Hash) or use global $Selector if declared ealier

Comment: I've updated it there to a basic level (I'm not actually hashing with md5).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm calling it from the login page if login is set to `true`. I've tested all these elements with echo statements. 
                `require("functions.php");
                updatecookieDB($db, $email)`

Comment: `$email` is the user id on login.

Comment: you didn't pass enough arguments

Comment: @Fred-ii- what's missing? Think I have code blindness.

Answer (score -2):

I changed it to the following and it worked correctly:

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query)->execute($query_params);
```

Comment: this is essentially the same as what you had before

Comment: Yeah I can't understand why it worked and the other did 't